# Prove limit is infinity by definition

Tags: calculus

> $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}=\infty $ prove by definition.

For all $M$, we need to find $\delta$ such that $0<|x-0|<\delta$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{x^2}>M$.

$$\frac{1}{x^2}>M\iff x^2<\frac{1}{M}\iff |x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt M} $$

Therefore we will take $\delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt M}$

Is it vaild? whenever we take a root out of $x^2$ is must be in absolute value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost completely, yes. If I were to nitpick, I'd say that $x^2 < \frac{1}{M} \not\implies \frac{1}{x^2} > M$, simply because the case of $x = 0$ is not excluded. However, I'd agree if this were modified to:
$$\frac{1}{x^2} > M \Longleftarrow 0 < x^2 < \frac{1}{M} \iff 0 < |x| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}.$$